# Calling objects dynamically

Tags: ruby, oop

```
class Person
    def sampleMethod
    end
end

jack = Person.new
input = gets.chomp
```

How can I call jack object through user input? I tried this:

```
input = gets.downcase.chomp.to_sym
```

It calls methods but objects.

I also tried this:

```
eval input + '.sampleMethod'
```

and this:

```
Kernel.const_get(input).sampleMethod
```

Please help.

Comment: What is the content of the input?

Comment: Why would you select an answer after only 20 minutes, when only one answer had been offered? Next time, I suggest you wait awhile (a few hours, say). There's no rush. A quick selection may discourage other, possibly better, answers, and is inconsiderate to those still working on their answers. Note that, if you select an answer and later another is given that you prefer, you can always change your selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store each person in a hash, where the keys of the hash are names that the person can be referred to.

```
class Person
  Registry = {}

  def sample_method
    puts 'hello, world'
  end
end

Person::Registry['jack'] = Person.new

name = 'jack'  # or you can use: name = gets.chomp    
person = Person::Registry.fetch(name)
person.sample_method
```

Using `eval` with user input is dangerous because it gives the users all sorts of ways they could accidentally or maliciously mess up your program.  I would not reach for `eval` as the first tool to solve this relatively simple problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Person
    def sampleMethod
       puts "hello, world"
    end
end

jack = Person.new
input = "jack"
```

you can use `eval` to call the object.

```
eval input
=> #<Person:0x007f916ba16c20>
eval input + ".sampleMethod"
hello, world
=> nil

jack.object_id
=> 70131276363280
(eval input).object_id
=> 70131276363280
```

they have the same object id, so they call the same object.

Comment: This is very bad advice. You should be telling the OP not to do that. Perhaps give some examples of the pain it could inflict, and I'm not just talking about giving out the keys to the castle. Suppose, for example, you had a class `CEO`, with children `VPs`, etc., all the way down to `WorkerBees`. If supervisors were allowed to identify `WorkerBee`s that were to be sent the method `admonish`, defined in `CEO`, let's just hope there were no spelling mistakes.  True, you might not do that in that context, but all sorts of unintended consequences would be possible if users could do that.